# Simulate localStorage data in test

Tags: reactjs, mocking, local-storage, jestjs

I am using Create React App.
I am trying to simulate `isLoggedIn` behaviour in my component to get all lines code coverage.
To do that localStorage key: `user` must exist with `data.accessToken`

I tried set localStorage data in the test but it is not working. the same method actually working in `isLoggedIn` function and generate 100% line coverage.

isLoggedIn function

```
export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  const userFromLocalStorage = store('user');
  return _get(userFromLocalStorage, 'data.accessToken', false);
};
```

PrivateRoute.js:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isLoggedIn() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: 'login' }} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

PrivateRoute.spec.js

```
import store from 'store2';
describe('PrivateRoute Logged In', () => {
  store('user', {
    data: {
      accessToken: 'dfg',
    },
  });

  const ShallowPrivateRoute = shallow(
    <PrivateRoute path="/" name="Home" component={TestComponent} />
  );

  it('should cover logged in case', () => {
    expect(ShallowPrivateRoute).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Is there the way I can mock `isLoggedIn` function to return true just for one test??

What is the best way to test that kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the entire file like this:

```
jest.mock("you-module", () =>({...methodsMock}));
```

or you could recieve isLoggedIn in props, that way you only need to pass a mock function when you render your component in test.

```
<Component isLoggedIn={jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)} />
```

Comment: what you mean my module?? if I am importing `import { isLoggedIn } from '../../helpers';`  is so is it `jest.mock('../../helpers', () => ({ isLoggedIn: () => true }));` ?? because its not working like that